# Give access to parts of the firebase realtime database according to uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

As the title suggests, I want to give access to different parts of the database to different users. I have only found the following in the official google documentation:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is give access to arbitrarily named nodes in the database. For example I want to give multiple users access to the same node, where this approach would not work. I have tried the following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "myNode": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === 1EAwd9b6d9YloPlLpf0tpyztKR12"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You need to put the string value in quotes. Also: if you want the rules to be specific to the current user, use `auth.uid`. So: `".write": "auth.uid === '1EAwd9b6d9YloPlLpf0tpyztKR12'"`. I highly recommend that you read the Firebase Database security guide end-to-end, because it contains a lot more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just found this out by experimenting a bit, but thanks anyway! Also: I read the Firebase Database security guide, but I didn't find the solution to my problem there

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the mistake with the '$uid' you pointed out was just a typo in the stackoverflow question. In my original code I used ''auth.uid"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation I found that the error was simply that the string value needs to be put in quotes. So the correct code is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "myNode": {
        ".write": "auth.uid === '1EAwd9b6d9YloPlLpf0tpyztKR12'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```